# Query returns same data every time it runs

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

Background:

Through these codes, I add different appeal numbers to the database. Each appeal number has an assignment code assigned to it through these codes.

Problem:

The problem is when I add more than 2 appeals simultaneously, this code only detects the assignment code assigned to 1st appeal added, but does not detect the next added assignment number.

I tried adding Thread.sleep method, but the result is same.

```vb
   Try
        ' Find out last assignment code
        Dim fillCommand As String
        Dim FillList As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim rowdata As Integer

        Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ComplianceDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxx;" 'D:\Important Programing links\Programming Learning\Compliance Diary\ComlianceDiary\ComlianceDiary\database\ComplianceDB.accdb"
        Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Conn.Open()

        If ListView1.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid information to add appeal.", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf BenchComboBox.Text = "" Or NoticeLocationTextBox.Text = "" Or BenchMembersTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter all the required information to add appeal.", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Else

            For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                'Add Appeals to ATIR list
                Me.ATIRTableAdapter.Insert(ClientComboBox.Text, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text, ListView1.Items(i).Text, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(2).Text, BenchComboBox.Text, BenchMembersTextBox.Text, HearingDate.Value.Date, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(4).Text, mgrComboBox.Text, txtdescription.Text, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(3).Text, NoticeLocationTextBox.Text, ChangePassword.GUIDTextBox.Text, DateAndTime.Today)

                Dim AssignmentCommand = New OleDbCommand("select AssignmentCode, AssignmentName from Assignment where AssignmentName = 'ATIR Appeal - " & ListView1.Items(i).Text & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientComboBox.Text & "'", Conn) ' (select max(AssignmentCode) from Assignment)"  'SELECT * FROM Assignment Where AssignmentName = '" & AssignmentNameTextBox.Text & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientNameComboBox.Text & "'" ' WHERE DateofHearing BETWEEN " & Today.Date & " AND " & Today.Date.AddDays(15)
                Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = AssignmentCommand.ExecuteReader
                'Check if the assignment name already exists, if yes, fetch old assignment code and add it to new compliance
                If Reader.Read Then
                    Dim ATIRCodeCmd = New OleDbCommand("select ID from ATIR where ID = (select max(ID) from ATIR)", Conn)  'SELECT * FROM Assignment Where AssignmentName = '" & AssignmentNameTextBox.Text & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientNameComboBox.Text & "'" ' WHERE DateofHearing BETWEEN " & Today.Date & " AND " & Today.Date.AddDays(15)
                    Dim ReaderATIRCode As OleDbDataReader = ATIRCodeCmd.ExecuteReader
                    While ReaderATIRCode.Read()
                        Me.NoticeComplianceTableAdapter1.Insert(ClientComboBox.Text, Reader.Item(1).ToString, Today.Date, Today.Date, Reader.Item(1).ToString, NoticeLocationTextBox.Text, txtdescription.Text, Reader.Item(0).ToString, "No", "", "", "Pending", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text, "", "", "", "Fresh Notice", "", "", ChangePassword.GUIDTextBox.Text, DateAndTime.Today, mgrComboBox.Text, PartnerNameTextBox.Text, SrManagerNameTextBox.Text, "AppellateCompliance", HearingDate.Value.Date, "", "", "", "", "", ReaderATIRCode.Item(0).ToString, "ATIR")
                    End While
                Else

                    'if assignment does not exists, then create a new one and give new assignment number to new compliance.
                    Me.AssignmentTableAdapter1.Insert(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text, ClientComboBox.Text, "ATIR Appeal - " & ListView1.Items(i).Text, "N/A", "Pending", "No", Today.Date, HearingDate.Value.Date, HearingDate.Value.Date, mgrComboBox.Text, SrManagerNameTextBox.Text, PartnerNameTextBox.Text, "Income Tax Ordinance, 2001", "Pending", "", "Pending", "", "Pending", "", Today.Date, "", Today.Date, "Pending", Today.Date, "")
                    Dim AssignmentCodeCmd = New OleDbCommand("select AssignmentCode from Assignment where AssignmentCode = (select max(AssignmentCode) from Assignment)", Conn)  'SELECT * FROM Assignment Where AssignmentName = '" & AssignmentNameTextBox.Text & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientNameComboBox.Text & "'" ' WHERE DateofHearing BETWEEN " & Today.Date & " AND " & Today.Date.AddDays(15)
                    Dim ReaderCode As OleDbDataReader = AssignmentCodeCmd.ExecuteReader
                    While ReaderCode.Read()
                        rowdata = ReaderCode.Item(0).ToString
                        ReaderCode.NextResult()
                    End While

                    Dim ATIRCodeCmd = New OleDbCommand("select ID from ATIR where ID = (select max(ID) from ATIR)", Conn)  'SELECT * FROM Assignment Where AssignmentName = '" & AssignmentNameTextBox.Text & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientNameComboBox.Text & "'" ' WHERE DateofHearing BETWEEN " & Today.Date & " AND " & Today.Date.AddDays(15)
                    'Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    Dim ReaderATIRCode As OleDbDataReader = ATIRCodeCmd.ExecuteReader
                    While ReaderATIRCode.Read()
                        Me.NoticeComplianceTableAdapter1.Insert(ClientComboBox.Text, "ATIR Appeal - " & ListView1.Items(i).Text, Today.Date, Today.Date, "ATIR Appeal - " & ListView1.Items(i).Text, NoticeLocationTextBox.Text, txtdescription.Text, rowdata, "No", "", "", "Pending", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text, "", "", "", "Fresh Notice", "", "", ChangePassword.GUIDTextBox.Text, DateAndTime.Today, mgrComboBox.Text, PartnerNameTextBox.Text, SrManagerNameTextBox.Text, "AppellateCompliance", HearingDate.Value.Date, "", "", "", "", "", ReaderATIRCode.Item(0).ToString, "ATIR")
                    End While

                End If
                Reader.Close()
            Next

            MessageBox.Show("ATIR Appeal(s) have been noted.", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Conn.Close()

            Me.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
```

Comment: ***NEVER EVER*** do something like `SELECT MAX(...) + 1` to get the "next highest" ID number - this is just ***NOT SAFE*** in a system with multiple users! Let the database handle this - just use auto numbering for these kinds of counters - an `Autonumber` in MS Access, or an `INT IDENTITY` column in SQL Server. Don't try to roll your own - just don't - use what the database gives you!

Comment: Please suggest me how can I achieve my purpose then.   Select MAX(..) is used to get the next highest value of ID from another table in the database. Which is more suitable command to get the highest value from another table.

Comment: I already **told you**: use the facilities the database provides - `autonumber` in MS Access, `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server ....

Comment: Also be **aware:** [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: `autonumber` is used to generate number in the same table. But, in my code, I have to get the assignment Code from another table, so that same can be entered in `NoticeCompliance` table.

Comment: Two possible ways to solve the PK-FK thing: you can use datasets and a tableadaptermanager, or despite marc_s' good advice, you can indeed roll your own - NOT using SELECT MAX, but using a row in  another table as a source of ID numbers. Create a stored procedure to increment and return the value of this row in one operation. This is an old-school approach from the days before Identity fields; it can be made to work reliably, but implemented carelessly can still suffer from race conditions on multi-user systems.

Comment: These guys are right, you may not realize it but manually setting this ID field is inevitably going to cause you some serious and unexpected grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I resolved my problem by using `@@IDENTITY` sql command. Thank you all for your contributions.